# How can I get screen workarea (not whole screen size) size in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, controls, screen

I want to get the screen workarea size in Silverlight. Now I can get the screen size by using below code:

```
actualWidth = (double)System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.width");
actualHeight = (double)System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.height");
```

But it returns whole screen size that includes the TaskBar also. But I want to get only workarea size that excludes taskbar and so on. Like `SystemParameters.WorkArea` in WPF.

Can anyone guide me to get only screen workarea size in Silverlight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

1. **`screen.availWidth`** - available screen Width
2. **`screen.availHeight`** - available screen Height

Note: The **`screen.availWidth`** property returns the Width of the visitor's screen, in pixels, minus interface features like the Windows Taskbar.